# C: Custom strlen() library function

Tags: c, types, char, sizeof, strlen

I created my version of `strlen()` function.

```
unsigned int my_strlen(char *p)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        p++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

It gives me correct output everytime i run.But my collegues are saying this code may cause problem on systems where length of character is greater than `1 byte`. Is that so ??

So they modified the code as following:

```
unsigned int my_strlen(char *p)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char *start = p;

    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        i++;
        p++;
    }

    return p - start;
}
```

I always thought in C a character is 1 byte long.

Is former snippet is better than the latter or vice versa ??

Comment: Your colleagues may be considering UTF character sets (for instance) where you have characters taking more than 8 bits (e.g., bigger than an octet). Your second implementation has an unused variable, so it's worse for that reason.

Comment: @markw Since UTF character take 2 bytes, so in this case char is 2 bytes long ?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic works the same way as array indexing. In both cases the compiler knows the data size. So `p++` is adjusted to point to the next data item, regardless of its size. Your friends are also wrong for keeping a copy of the function argument and incrementing `p`, it should be the other way round - modify the copy of the argument.

Comment: @Cody in my experience, UTF usually requires working with so-called 'wide characters' which hold more than a single char. Depending on your platform, a wide character could be the same size as a char.

Comment: Multiplying `i` by `sizeof(char)`, which is always 1, is unnecessary but harmless.  You would want to do so for any other type.

Answer (score 7):

It is guaranteed in C that `sizeof(char)` is 1, so you are right.

To add some authenticity, directly quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4, *The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators*

> When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
>   `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. [....]

That said, pointer arithmetic honors the data type, so the second approach does not make any sense in the respect of what is is *expected* to do, anyway. Both the case, you're operating on `p`, which is `char*`, so the effect will be the same.

Comment: so both versions are equivalent ?

Comment: @Cody I'd say, the first one is better.

Comment: what about UTF characters ? do they take more than 1 byte ?

Comment: @Cody Yes, they take more than 1 byte, but that's not how you hadle UTF in C. Generally we use some other library (qt) to handle them.

Comment: pls share the link of the reference you quoted

Comment: @Cody Moreover, whatever be the encoding, C access the raw data, byte by byte while using a `char` pointer which points to the memory, so that should not be a concern anyway.

Comment: @Cody which link? C standard?

Comment: @Cody well, the actual standards are not available freely, you can check a near-perfect copy [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Is Qt commonly used in C? (It's a C++ interface.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Did not use myself, got the referances. [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html#Top) is another alternative.

Comment: IIRC, I downvoted before the edits because without the reference to pointer arithmetic, confirming that sizeof(char) = 1 doesn't answer the question about the difference (or lack of a difference) between implementations.

Comment: Yes. I can't remove the downvote though if that's where you're headed... It looks like it wasn't edited since I made my comment, but anyway, I don't have a problem with the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

As you use `p++`, you increment you pointer by `sizeof(char)`. Hence, it's not relevant what is `sizeof(char)` even if it was variable between different machines. Your colleagues are wrong.

Note: If you want to count the bytes, and not the characters, then your colleagues could be correct (if char was not guaranteed to be 1 byte, but it is). If you want to count the characters, then your colleagues are just wrong at all.

Answer (score 1):

OP posted "length of **character** is greater than 1 byte", not `char`.  OP is right when one limits a *character* to only `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`.   Those 3 *always* have a size of 1.

OP's colleagues may not all think in that restrictive sense.  The C spec has many *character* types: *single-byte character*, *multibyte character*, *extended character*, *wide character*, not all 1 byte.

Modified code has weakness.  It does not sensible relate to "length of character is greater than 1 byte".  Also, the `i++;` is pointless.  The return type of `unsigned` maybe insufficient.  Use `size_t` for an unsigned type that is neither too wide nor narrow.

```
// simplify
size_t my_strlen2(const char *p) {
    const char *start = p;
    while(*p) p++;
    return (size_t) (p - start);
}
```

> Is former snippet is better than the latter or vice versa ??

Neither returns a type that will not overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Although the others answered your question regarding the character size, your version is still not correct.

The current standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) is short and precise here:

> **7.24.6.3 The `strlen` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <string.h>`<br>
>     size_t strlen(const char *s);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 The `strlen` function computes the length of the string pointed to by s.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3 The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede the
>   terminating null character.

So a fully compliant function would be

```
size_t stringlength(const char *s){
  size_t i = 0;
  while(s && *s != '\0'){
      s++;
      i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

The main difference is that it checks the input (could be `NULL`, but e.g.: glibc's `strlen` segfaults. If you want it to segfault, strip the test for `s == NULL` in the loop. Segfaulting is probably the better alternative, otherwise you get the sort of bugs we like to call "Heisenbugs". Bugs that tend to disappear when you look at them and their waveform collapses) and uses `size_t` as the output.

The Glibc version handles several bytes at once if and when possible--don't know if such an optimization is useful.

If you want the equivalent of `wsclen()` you can do something like that:

```
#include <wchar.h>
size_t wstringlength(const wchar_t *s){
  size_t i = 0;
  while(s[i] != L'\0'){
      i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Counting multibyte characters (`mbrlen()` checks for one character only, but you can use `mbrtowc()`) is quite complicated and out of the scope of this short post.

Comment: The test  `s == NULL` is not needed for C standard library compliance.  If used, suggest not having it as part of the `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` function using `for`:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {

    size_t n;

    for (n = 0; *s; s++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

Or:

```
size_t n;

for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
    n++;
return n;
```

Or:

```
size_t n;

for (n = 0; *(s++); )
    n++;
return n;
```

Or:

```
size_t n;

for (n = 0; *s; n++)
    s++;
return n;
```

Or:

```
size_t n = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; s[i]; i++)
    n++;
return n;
```

Answer (score -2):

In terms of Pointer arithmetic, It is not going to give you different result on platform having char as 2 bytes long as you are working on pointers and pointer arithmetic always stick to data types.
Here is another way of finding string len, which do not use pointer airthmetic-

```
int len  = -1;
while(p[++len] != '\0');
return len;
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you defend your assertion?

Comment: `while(p[len] != '\0') { len++; }`

Comment: "*... on platform having char as 2 bytes long ...*" By definition, there are no such platforms.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I mean for UTF char set

Comment: If you mean UTF-8, or UTF-16, or UTF-32, those are representations of the Unicode character set; they're not character sets themselves. In any case, `sizeof (char) == 1` **by definition**. (The number of bits in a byte may (rarely) vary.)

Comment: increment and decrements as index is undefined behavior