# Custom Reverse and strlen functions in C

Tags: c

My task is
Realization of function reverse.When implementing a function, it is forbidden to use the functions of the C language libraries.
Can someone help me with the realization of function strlen?

My function:

```
void revstr( char * str){
    int i, len = 0;

    len = strlen(str);

    for (i = 0; i <= len / 2; i++){
        *(str + len - i) = *(str + i);  
        *(str + i) = *(str + len - i - 1);
    } 


    for (i = len / 2; i <= len; i++)
        *(str + i) = *(str + i + 1);

}
```

Comment: `strlen` counts the characters until it reaches the character `0x00`. This info will be enough I guess.

Comment: `*(str + len - i)` and alike is unreadable. Use `str[len - i]`

Comment: Write code rhat swaps two values (e.g. characters). Test, then test some more, make sure it works, *then* proceed to write `reverse`.

Comment: @bolov It's a homework, I found this syntax useful to learn pointer arithmetic.

Comment: *Can someone help me with the realization of function strlen?*  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438991/c-custom-strlen-library-function

Comment: @Hell, here, it will be a better idea if you select the answer which help you solve your question. So, Other user also get that the question is answered. :)

Answer (score 3):

strlen returns the length of the string. So you can iterate through whole string, increment a counter and return the counter as the length

code:

```
size_t my_strlen(char *str) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) 
        ;
    return i;
}
```

#### Edit:

Your revstr code seems really complex. Here is a simple way of doing that.

```
char * revstr( char * str)
{
    int i,end,len;
    char temp;

    len= my_strlen(str);
    end = len-1;
    for(i=0;i<len/2;i++)
    {
       temp=str[i];
       str[i]=str[end];
       str[end--]=temp;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Note: It is good practice to write `str[i]` instead of `*(str + i)`. 
and the code works perfect for your question :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.!

Comment: You could use `int end = my_strlen(str) - 1; for (int i = 0; i < end; i++, end--) { …swap… }`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's ever *"forbidden"* to use standard library functions, using `strlen()` here is fine. Their is no need to write your own. As for your reverse function, I suggest you break down the problem.

A simple approach is to have two counters, one which starts at the beginning of the string, and one that starts at the end of the string. You'll need to swap these characters, which can be done like this:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b) {
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Once these start and end characters are swapped, increment the start counter and decrement the end counter to move inward the string, and swap again. This can be written in a simple loop:

```
for (start = 0, end = len-1; start <= end; start++, end--) {
    swap(&string[start], &string[end]);
}
```

I'll let you fill in the rest of the code, but this gives the general idea.

Comment: In homework assignments, it is common for specific standard functions to be forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
void revstr(char *str)
{
    char *s = str;
    char *e;

    for (e=s; *e; ++e); //find the end

    if (e==s)
        return; //empty string

    for (--e; e>s; --e,++s)
    {
        char t = *s;
        *s = *e;
        *e = t;
    }
}
```